# ELECTRICAL problem with stove

Tags: electrical

Have Fridgidaire stove, says on back 3 wire AC only. Recently I moved, outlet for stove is 4 wire, I changed plug from 3 wire to 4 wire plug.  Seems everything works fine, problem is with display board. Clock is dim, and I cannot set temperature for baking display, does not light up. Is board faulty, or not working because I rewired from 3 to 4 wire?  Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you wired it wrong. Need: picture of receptacle, picture of wires from cord where they attach to stove. Get a multimeter and report voltage readings between every pair of holes in the receptacle.

Comment: What's the stove model?   Post a picture of the electrical requirements from the manual also.

Comment: What did you do inside the range with the fourth, probably green, wire from your 4-wire plug?

Comment: 4-wire is vastly safer and should not affect anything.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Could be something like a hot/neutral swap (ground/neutral swap no immediate consequence, hot/ground swap is scary). That would result in 120V hot to hot (because hot to neutral), 240V one hot to neutral (because hot to hot) and 120V other hot to neutral. Which would result in a *lot* of crazy stuff.

Comment: There are 240v 3 wire stoves that do not use the neutral just like most water heaters depending on the type of device 4 wire may have no impact on safety if properly wired. What model is the stove and how is the 4 wire connected? A photo would be good here.

Comment: @Ed yeah, but those are just range tops and don't have ovens.  The neutral is needed for the oven light.

Comment: Could be a lost neutral wire too.

Comment: What model is this stove of yours? Also, can you post photos of any wiring diagrams on the appliance, and how the cord is wired to the range?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible you've miswired the stove and put the neutral on a hot terminal. Most likely the stoves power supply for the computer derives it's power from a hot to neutral connection, but not necessarily. You could either be over volting or under volting the power supply. Recheck your wiring and make sure you have the correct colors matched up.

Also, make sure you remove the copper bonding strap from the neutral conductor. And make sure the white wire is on that terminal.